# Float and double rounding in C

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, double

I went upon a very strange behavior (to me) :

```cs
    int generate_scenario_one_pass(FILE *out, double freq_mhz) {
        unsigned int d_freq, d_freq_test;
        d_freq              = (int)(freq_mhz * 20);
        d_freq_test         = (int)(float)(freq_mhz * 20);
        printf("when freq_mhz = %.1f, d_freq = 0x%04X, d_freq_test = 0x%04X\n", freq_mhz, d_freq, d_freq_test);
    }
```

The whole code is not here, but it's not relevant. This function is called several times with increasing values, starting from 2110.0 with an increment of 0.1.

```
when freq_mhz = 2110.0, d_freq = 0xA4D8, d_freq_test = 0xA4D8
when freq_mhz = 2110.1, d_freq = 0xA4DA, d_freq_test = 0xA4DA
when freq_mhz = 2110.2, d_freq = 0xA4DC, d_freq_test = 0xA4DC
when freq_mhz = 2110.3, d_freq = 0xA4DD, d_freq_test = 0xA4DE
```

At the last iteration, `d_freq` is wrong! But `d_freq_test` has the correct value. So my issue was solved by casting from `double` to `float`, then from `float` to `int`. I wanted to know why.

This was compiled using MSVC++ 6.0 on a x86 CPU.

Comment: If you're only working at precision to 10ths, and you're multiplying by 20... why not just take an int representing the 10ths, e.g. 21100 and multiply by 2?

Comment: I'm working with a microchip that has this value hardcoded as 20 times the actual value. I can't change that, it's hardware.

Comment: The point is you get the same result. You still get 20*freq, because it's 2*(freq*10), but freq*10 is an integer, so you save yourself the hassle of dealing with issues like this.

Comment: The actual precision of the chip is 0.05, and for my test I just need it to go every 0.1

Comment: Il'll try to rephrase @FatalError idea: why don't you use fixed point (i.e. an int with an implicit divisor of 10 or 20 or whatever you need) instead of floating point. It is usually more predictable as long as your divisor can stay the same for the whole program. (Floating point can be considered as the case where the divisor is different for each value and is a power of 2).

Comment: Oh, right, I'm sorry. My program takes its input values (for freq_mhz) from the user, which is inputted as a float, for example 2110.0 or 2622.4. So I *have* to convert from float to x20 int

Comment: @Bicou, such conversion are better done at IO time (using a round to nearest when reading, ensuring you output only valid value when writing; you don't necessary have to use FP at the time) and then do the whole computation using fixed point. I've worked on a program which didn't do that, we saw the end of related bug stream only when the (progressive, management was against a global effort but could do nothing against the piecewise approach we used) switch to fixed point was completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many numbers that cannot be represented exactly as a floating-point number - and 0.1 is among them (it will be rounded to the closest number that *can* be represented - something along the lines of 0.0999999999999998). When using `double`, 2110.3 happens to be represented by a number that is slightly smaller than 2110.3, thus giving the "wrong" result when you multiply by 20 and cast to `int` (which will round down), while 2110.3 as a float will be represented by a number that is slightly bigger than 2110.3, thus giving the expected outcome.

Comment: "floating-point numbers are inherently inaccurate" - this is somewhat misleading...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Better now?

Comment: This best explains the problem I faced, +1 and I'll accept when I'll be able to. Check also my answer that shows the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10896637/334493

Answer (score 2):

Actually my double casting was not the solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int d_freq, d_freq_test;
    double freq_mhz = 2110.0;
    double step = 0.1;

    while (freq_mhz < 2111.0) {
        d_freq = (int)(freq_mhz * 20.0);
        d_freq_test = (int)(float)(freq_mhz * 20.0);
        printf("freq: %.1f, d_freq: 0x%04X, d_freq_test: 0x%04X\n", freq_mhz, d_freq, d_freq_test);
        freq_mhz += step;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this produces (wrong):

```
freq: 2110.0, d_freq: 0xA4D8, d_freq_test: 0xA4D8
freq: 2110.1, d_freq: 0xA4DA, d_freq_test: 0xA4DA
freq: 2110.2, d_freq: 0xA4DC, d_freq_test: 0xA4DC
freq: 2110.3, d_freq: 0xA4DD, d_freq_test: 0xA4DD <-- :(
freq: 2110.4, d_freq: 0xA4DF, d_freq_test: 0xA4DF
freq: 2110.5, d_freq: 0xA4E1, d_freq_test: 0xA4E1
freq: 2110.6, d_freq: 0xA4E3, d_freq_test: 0xA4E3
freq: 2110.7, d_freq: 0xA4E5, d_freq_test: 0xA4E5
freq: 2110.8, d_freq: 0xA4E7, d_freq_test: 0xA4E7
freq: 2110.9, d_freq: 0xA4E9, d_freq_test: 0xA4E9
freq: 2111.0, d_freq: 0xA4EB, d_freq_test: 0xA4EB
```

While this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int d_freq, d_freq_test;
    double freq_mhz = 2110.0;
    double step = 0.1;

    while (freq_mhz < 2111.0) {
        d_freq = (int)(freq_mhz * 20.0);
        d_freq_test = (int)(float)(freq_mhz * 20.0 + 0.5);
        printf("freq: %.1f, d_freq: 0x%04X, d_freq_test: 0x%04X\n", freq_mhz, d_freq, d_freq_test);
        freq_mhz += step;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
freq: 2110.0, d_freq: 0xA4D8, d_freq_test: 0xA4D8
freq: 2110.1, d_freq: 0xA4DA, d_freq_test: 0xA4DA
freq: 2110.2, d_freq: 0xA4DC, d_freq_test: 0xA4DC
freq: 2110.3, d_freq: 0xA4DD, d_freq_test: 0xA4DE <-- :)
freq: 2110.4, d_freq: 0xA4DF, d_freq_test: 0xA4E0
freq: 2110.5, d_freq: 0xA4E1, d_freq_test: 0xA4E2
freq: 2110.6, d_freq: 0xA4E3, d_freq_test: 0xA4E4
freq: 2110.7, d_freq: 0xA4E5, d_freq_test: 0xA4E6
freq: 2110.8, d_freq: 0xA4E7, d_freq_test: 0xA4E8
freq: 2110.9, d_freq: 0xA4E9, d_freq_test: 0xA4EA
freq: 2111.0, d_freq: 0xA4EB, d_freq_test: 0xA4EC
```

which is right.

So it was indeed rounding issue, a precision issue, which was solved by adding 0.5 to the result of the x20 multiplication.

Comment: you've still got the `(float)` cast in there, so what makes you think the `+0.5` helps?

Comment: @MartinThompson: That will cause the truncation to do a round-to-nearest, rather than a floor (at least for positive values).

Comment: @MartinThompson: casting using `(int)` or `(int)(float)` yields the same result.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: yes, my point was that this code still has the `(int)(float)` in it which causes (AIUI) rounding to happen *anyway*, so the +0.5 isn't actually being tested.

Answer (score 2):

When you convert from double to int, you get truncation.

The value of `freq_mhz*20` at `2110.3` is represented by `0x40E49BFFFFFFFFFF` - which is 42207.9999999999927240423858166.  When you truncate that to an `int`, the .999999 gets chopped off and you get 42207 (or 0xA4DD - why choose to represent these in hex?)

If you convert to a float in the meantime, you get a rounding operation performed.  What you actually want to do is explicitly call `round` on the value and then convert to an `int`.

Comment: From the frequencies involved, I'd be willing to be that the OP is generating register values for a hardware PLL or RF synth or something for a wireless transceiver (UMTS, probably).  Hence hex is a natural representation to choose.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Agreed, but in terms of "explaining the question most obviously", decimal numbers make more sense (IMHO :)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: that is entirely correct, I'm driving a RFIC chip for UMTS/LTE.

Comment: @MartinThompson: the value x20 doesn't make any sense, hence the hex notation.

Comment: @Bicou: Sorry, that comment wasn't meant to wind anyone up - all I meant was that the *question* you have is not dependent on your application. It's easier to see what's going on comparing a double with a decimal integer, as they are both displayed in the same base.

Comment: @MartinThompson: I see what you mean.  I didn't mean to post a rude comment, I'm sorry.  It's also because I read a lot of these values in hex, so A4D8 *has* a meaning to my eyes ;)

Comment: @Bicou: no problem - we all have our own set of "hex-values-we-just-see-without-thinking" :)

Answer (score 1):

Because 0.1 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating-point.  What you are seeing are approximations, exacerbated by the truncation that casting causes, and the rounding that `printf` causes.

One way to solve this is to explicitly round instead of truncating when casting to int (you could use `round()`).

Comment: Someone who think precision = accuracy? Got me as well.

Answer (score 0):

a tenth cannot be represented in binary. It's like a 1/3 in base ten. The more places after decimal point you get the closer you are but you can't get there. There are all sorts of coping strategies but basicall if you want exact representation, floating point formats won't do it. Fixed point (decimal) formats are required.